# QBasic Break Key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I wrote a loop in QBasic (running with Boxer, on a MacBook Air) that I can't stop in-app because I need to use the Break key.

I'm used to PC keyboards that have a key labeled break and I don't know how to do this on the Apple keyboard.

Is there an equivalent key or software I can easily press "break" so it's sent to the running App as if I had a physical keyboard?

Comment: Is there a version of Boxer for OSX/macOS?

Comment: @patrix That's what I'm using.

Comment: In te Boxer menu Emulation->Send Key-> Break

Answer (score 1):

You can always terminate applications via the Apple
Menu or by using Activity Monitor.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I want a way to terminate the code in-app